# How do I use a regular expression to do a "find and replace" operation in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to use a regex to find strings like `,--#` (where # is any digit) and replace them with `,+#` (where # is the digit matched previously).

I can come up with the find part. `/(\,--\d)/g` finds the text I am looking for. But I cannot find a way to replace it using a regex.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `s` (substitution) operator, not just a regex. A regex will let you find the text; `s` will let you find and replace.

The first part is the pattern that matches what you want, and the second is the *string* that gets substituted for *all* of what was matched. If you need to potentially match this multiple times in a line, you add the `g` (globally) suffix.

```
$line =~ s/,--(\d+)/,+$1/g;
```

This finds every `,--` followed by one or more digits (captured by the parens in `$1`), and substitutes the string `,+$1`, which interpolates the captured number into the string.

If `,--` doesn't occur in any other context than this, you could eliminate the need for capturing the number and just substitute the string:

```
$line =~ s/,--/,+/g;
```

Edit: If the "find" string is always only one digit, then you don't need `\d+`; `\d` will do to capture a single digit. It's habit for me to assume that there'll probably be a case where I need to capture an integer, not just a single digit.

Edit again: clarifying that a regex was a step in the right direction, but substitution is the way to do a "find and replace" operation.